# SQL query issue with achieving an encompasses all effect

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Below is the query I have been working on for this question.

Find the names of the companies which have employees residing in every city where employees of Mutual of Omaha live.

This means that if Mutual has employees in the cities Omaha, Lincoln, and Denver that the only company names it should return is a company that has employees in all 3 of those cities. This should also return Mutual.

The below query returns the company which has an employee in any of those three cities. The lastname is there for me to manually check which employees it is counting.

```
    SELECT COMPANY_NAME, e1.lastname
    FROM EMPLOYEE E1,WORKS W1 
    WHERE E1.CITY IN (SELECT CITY 
      FROM EMPLOYEE E2,WORKS W2 
      WHERE E2.firstname = W2.firstname
        AND E2.lastname = W2.lastname 
        AND W2.COMPANY_NAME= 'Mutual of Omaha')  
    AND E1.firstname = W1.firstname 
    AND E1.lastname = W1.lastname;
```

I realized I didn't put the tables down so here they are

employee (Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, gender, street, city)

works (Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, company_name, salary)

manages(Lastname, FirstName, MidInitial, ManagerLastname, MFirstName, MMidInitial, start-date)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How do I make multiple checks to make sure that all cities are covered. As my query above only checks if 1 city matches and not all.

Comment: what is the `manages` table for? you shoud post some example data and explain what you mean for `mutual`

Comment: How many distinct cities are there? I'm pondering a "bitmap" field as I've used them for matching lists in the past and they are fairly simple queries for the most part but are limited by the amount of distinct items in the list

Comment: Mutual just meant that even if no other company has employees in all the same cities it should still return Mutual of Omaha. Also in my practice database there are only 5 different cities, but I assume it could be unlimited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most elegant piece of code, but try using this one:

```
WITH tab AS (
SELECT DISTINCT W1.COMPANY_NAME, 
       E1.CITY
  FROM EMPLOYEE E1
  JOIN WORKS W1 ON (E1.firstname = W1.firstname AND E1.lastname = W1.lastname)
 WHERE E1.CITY IN (SELECT DISTINCT E2.CITY
                     FROM EMPLOYEE E2,WORKS W2 
                    WHERE E2.firstname = W2.firstname
                      AND E2.lastname = W2.lastname 
                      AND W2.COMPANY_NAME= 'Mutual of Omaha')
)
SELECT tab.COMPANY_NAME
  FROM tab 
 GROUP BY tab.COMPANY_NAME
HAVING COUNT(tab.CITY) = (SELECT COUNT(sub.CITY) FROM tab sub WHERE COMPANY_NAME = 'Mutual of Omaha')
```

Comment: I think that the `count(*)` does not guarantee that the cities are the same for both companies

Comment: @MtwStark when it's intermingled *distinct company_name, city* as I have written, then it does. Have you tried running the code on your test tables?

Comment: This seems to work. I'm going to change my database up a bit and test it again

Answer (score 0):

I would start with a CTE that has each company with the cities they operate in.

Then there are several options, but a self-join with aggregation does the count that you want:

```
with cw as (
      select distinct e.city, w.company_name
      from employee e join
           works w
           on e.firstname = w.firstname and
              e.lastname = w.lastname and
              e.midinitial = w.midinitial
     )
select cw.company_name
from cw join
     cw cwo
     on cw.city = cwo.city and
        cwo.company_name = 'Mutual of Omaha'
group by cw.company_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from cw where 
cw.company_name = 'Mutual of Omaha');
```

Comment: where did cwo come from?

Comment: @rick . . . It is an alias for `cw`.

Answer (score 0):

You can list and weight the cities where companies have employees, so you will get a single number representing each company based on where they have their employees, a sort of group number.

Then you can check which cities have the same group number.

```
;with
cities as(select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by city) city_id, city from (select distinct city from employees) c),
chk as (
    select distinct company_name, city_id
    from works w
    join employees e on w.firstname = e.firstname and w.lastname = e.lastname
    join cities c on c.city = e.city
),
cnt as (
    select company_name, SUM(power(cast(2 as bigint), city_id-1)) n
    from chk
    group by company_name
)
select company_name
from cnt
where n = (select n from cnt where company_name = 'Mutual of Omaha')
```

Answer (score 0):

This option uses the [bitwise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) operator so is also limited by the number of cities it can use at once (~31 due to Int size limit)

```
    ------------Assign each distinct city a value that is x2 the previous (like binary counting)
    create table #cityvalues (CityName varchar(100), ValueField int)
    select distinct E1.CITY
    into #while
    FROM EMPLOYEE E1


    while (select count(*) from #while) > 0
    begin
    insert into #cityvalues 
    select top 1 CITY, coalesce((select max(ValueField) from #cityvalues)*2, 1) from #while 
    delete from #while w where w.CITY in (select CityName from #CityValues)
    end
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    --------------Create a list of Company/City--------------------------------
    create table #companycities (Compname varchar(100),CityName varchar(100))
    insert into #companycities
    select distinct 
    W1.COMPANY_NAME
    ,E1.CITY
    FROM EMPLOYEE E1
    JOIN WORKS W1 on E1.firstname = W1.firstname  AND E1.lastname = W1.lastname
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    ----This SUM function then creates a "list" of all cities for the company in a single field 
    select cc.Compname, sum(cv.ValueField) as AllCities
    into #CompanyAllCities
    from #companycities cc
    join #cityvalues cv on cc.CityName = cv.CityName
    group by Compname
    -----------------------------------------------------------------


    ----------This query checks if the company's "list" contains the "list" for the joined company, excluding itself
    select distinct cac1.Compname 
    from #CompanyAllCities cac1
    join #CompanyAllCities cac2 on cac2.Compname = 'Mutual'
    where  cac2.AllCities & cac1.AllCities = cac2.AllCities
    and cac1.Compname <> 'Mutual'
    -------------------------------------------------------------


    ----------Tidy up after yourself----------
    drop table #cityvalues,#CompanyAllCities,#companycities
    -----------------------------------------
```